# MS-Access report ignores criteria on some but not all Win-10 PCs

Tags: migration, parameter-passing, report, ms-access-2010, criteria

We’ve run into a strange situation migrating our workstations from Windows 7 to Windows 10.  One of our migrated apps is based on MS-Access 2010.  Via the app’s user interface, users can open various criteria-driven forms & reports.  These forms & reports have all worked fine for years.  They also work fine on most of our new Windows 10 workstations (some of which are brand new PCs, while others are older PCs upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10).  But, on 2 of our Windows 10 workstations, one of the criteria-driven reports produces very different results than are produced when the same report is run with the same criteria on any of the other Windows 7 or Windows 10 workstations.  This particular report is opened when the user clicks a button on a form, after typing in the desired report criteria.  Clicking the button executes a `Docmd.openreport reportname,  acPreview,, criteria` action.  The problem is that on these 2 problematic Windows 10 workstations the report returns every record from the database—not just the few records corresponding to the criteria input by the user.  It’s as though the report’s query isn’t receiving the criteria, or is receiving them but is ignoring them.  We’ve done a lot of unsuccessful experimenting trying to figure out why we get different results on these 2 machines.  Can anyone suggest a troubleshooting approach?

Comment: Show criteria string (containing formated dates or other language/region depending data?). Patch-level runtime/OS, language/region settings? Same on all? Reinstalled OS/software?

Comment: The criteria string contains only text; no dates or language/region dependent data.  For example, `DoCmd.OpenReport PTPortfolio, acPreview, , “client=””V043”””` where PTPortfolio is the report name and the report criteria is the string value: client=”V043”